# How to call callback function after dispatch action Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, callback

I use React Redux and I create a function to login, but I need to get a callback return after successfull login and redirect user to a page.

I try to passing function as parameter but not working.

How can I get the return after dispatch action?

> ```
> Login fun
> ```

```
export const login = (request,cb) => {
           return dispatch => {
                let url = "/api/user/login";
                axios({
                    method: "post",
                    url: url,
                    data: request,
                    config: { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } }
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        let authState = {
                            isLoggedIn: true,
                            user: response.data
                        };
                        cb();
                        window.localStorage["authState"] = JSON.stringify(authState);
                        return dispatch({
                            type: "USER_LOGIN_FULFILLED",
                            payload: { userAuthData: response.data }
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        return dispatch({
                            type: "USER_LOGIN_REJECTED",
                            payload: err
                        });
                    });
           };
    };
```

> submiting

```
handleLogin(e) {
        this.setState({ showLoader: true });
        e.preventDefault();
        const request = new Object();
        if (this.validator.allValid()) {
            request.email = this.state.email;
            request.password = this.state.password;
            this.props.login(request, () => {
                //get callbach here
                this.props.history.push('/my-space/my_views');
            })

            this.setState({ showLoader: false });

        } else {
            this.setState({ showLoader: false });
            this.validator.showMessages();
            this.forceUpdate();
        }
    }
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        authState: state
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        login: request => dispatch(login(request))
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Answer (score 2):

The cb is missing in your connect(...)

Here is the fix

```
handleLogin(e) {
        this.setState({ showLoader: true });
        e.preventDefault();
        const request = new Object();
        if (this.validator.allValid()) {
            request.email = this.state.email;
            request.password = this.state.password;
            this.props.login(request, () => {
                //get callbach here
                this.props.history.push('/my-space/my_views');
            })

            this.setState({ showLoader: false });

        } else {
            this.setState({ showLoader: false });
            this.validator.showMessages();
            this.forceUpdate();
        }
    }
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        authState: state
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        login: (request, cb) => dispatch(login(request, cb))
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: I posted the answer, cb is missing in mapDispatchToProps
login: (request, cb) => dispatch(login(request, cb))

Comment: yes i forgot add this params in mapDispatchToProps  thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `redux-thunk`, you can return a `Promise` from your [`async action`](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions/#actionsjs-asynchronous).

> ```
> The function called by the thunk middleware can return a value,
> that is passed on as the return value of the dispatch method.
> In this case, we return a promise to wait for.
> This is not required by thunk middleware, but it is convenient for us.
> ```

But I prefer use `useEffect` or `componentDidUpdate` for this purpose:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
  if(this.props.authState.isLoggedIn){
    this.props.history.push('/my-space/my_views');  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Redux Cool](https://redux-cool.js.org/) package if you need actions with callback capability.

### Instalation

```sh
npm install redux-cool
```

## Usage

```js
import {actionsCreator} from "redux-cool"


const my_callback = () => {
    console.log("Hello, I am callback!!!")
}

const callbackable_action = actionsCreator.CALLBACKABLE.EXAMPLE(1, 2, 3, my_callback)

console.log(callbackable_action)
//      {
//          type: "CALLBACKABLE/EXAMPLE",
//          args: [1, 2, 3],
//          cb: f() my_callback,
//          _index: 1
//      }

callbackable_action.cb()
//      "Hello, I am callback!!!"
```

When we try to generate an action object, we can pass the callback function as the last argument. `actionsCreator` will check and if the last argument is a function, it will be considered as a callback function.

See [Actions Creator](https://redux-cool.js.org/docs/concepts/actions-creator) for more details

Answer (score 0):

react-redux/redux dispatch returns a promise. you can do this if you want to return a value or identify if the request is success/error after being dispatched

**Action example**

```
export const fetchSomething = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetchFromApi();
        dispatch({
            type: ACTION_TYPE,
            payload: response.value
        });
        return Promise.resolve(response.value);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
const foo = async data => {
    const response = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dispatch(fetchSomething())
            .then(v => resolve(v)) 
            .catch(err => reject(err)) 
    });
    await response 
        .then((v) => navigateToSomewhere("/", { replace: true }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

this post is old, but hopefully it will help

**Package.json**

```
   "react-redux": "^8.0.2"
   "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about sending callback function as parameter to action creator? It works for my login logic.

component:

```js
  // inside the component
  const loginCallback = () => {
    history.push(location.state.referrer);
  };

  const handleLogin = (loginData) => {
    dispatch(loginActionCreator(loginData, loginCallback));
  };
```

action creator:

```js
// inside the action creator

export const loginActionCreator =
  (loginData, loginCallback) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
      type: userActions.setFetchState,
      payload: FETCH_STATES.FETCHING,
    });
    doSRRequest(srEndpoints.login(loginData))
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: userActions.setUser,
          payload: res,
        });
        dispatch({
          type: userActions.setFetchState,
          payload: FETCH_STATES.FETHCED,
        });
        loginCallback();
      })
  };
```